# F# Val without Self Identifier

Tags: f#

Just curious why F# has:
`member val Foo = ... with get, set`
While omitting the self identifier (e.g. `this.`).
This is still an instance property. Maybe I am the only one confused when using it. But just bothered me enough to query whoever knows how the language was defined.

Comment: It is the same as auto-implemented properties in C#. `public int Foo { get; set; }`

Comment: @Petr that doesn't really explain it, though.  Many aspects of F# syntax -- especially the self identifier in other member declarations -- differ from C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this syntax, the property is almost totally auto-implemented -- all you provide is the initialization code, which essentially runs as part of the constructor.

One of the best-practice guard rails F# puts in place is that it does not let you access instance members before the instance is fully initialized. (wow, crazy idea, right?).

So you would have no use for a self-identifier in auto-props, anyways, since the only code you get to write is init code that can't touch instance members.

Per the MSDN docs (emphasis mine):

> Automatically implemented properties are part of the initialization of
>   a type, so they must be included before any other member definitions,
>   just like let bindings and do bindings in a type definition. **Note that
>   the expression that initializes an automatically implemented property
>   is only evaluated upon initialization, and not every time the property
>   is accessed. This behavior is in contrast to the behavior of an
>   explicitly implemented property. What this effectively means is that
>   the code to initialize these properties is added to the constructor of
>   a class.**

Btw, if you try to be a smartass and use the class-level self-identifier to get around this, you'll still blow up at runtime:

```
type A() as this =
    member val X =
        this.Y + 10
        with get, set

    member this.Y = 42

let a = A()

System.InvalidOperationException: The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized.
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions.FailInit()
   at FSI_0013.A.get_Y()
   at FSI_0013.A..ctor()
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0014>.$FSI_0014.main@()
```

**Edit:** Worth noting that in upcoming C# 6, they also now allow auto-props with initializers (more F# features stolen for C#, shocker :-P), and there is a similar restriction that you can't use the self-identifier:

```
class A
{
    // error CS0027: Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context
    public int X { get; set; } = this.Y + 10;
    public int Y = 42;
    public A() { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @latkin. I guess my question is answer. Though I still wonder a bit about it, as if this is mutable, wouldn't you be able to SET it to anything anywhere else, after the constructor?! I may be wrong ... but if you could -then you can use `this.` or anything else.

Comment: You can set the property from some *other* member like `this.MyProp <- 42`, sure.  But the setter code itself is auto-generated, so you don't write any actual code for it.

Comment: well I may have just asked a silly question altogether. Thank you @latkin again. The answer is probably what you wrote and the fact that as you point out the assignment is within the constructor, and thus the self identifier is omitted. The self identifier is therefore not reflecting on the get,set which are still related to the instance.